# cannot update a new record on after_create callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :set_slug

  def set_slug
    update_column(:slug, to_slug)
  end

  def to_slug
    #code to create slug
  end
end
```

Why does this return 'ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError: cannot update a new record' if the callback is an after_create? The issue is with "update_column"

Comment: it is working with me

Comment: paste the  full error stack.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem lies in the fact that `update_columns` doesn't work on new records. 
Why not use update_attributes` instead

```
  after_create do
    self.update_attributes(slug: to_slug)
  end
```

if you want then you can also try following approach

```
if new_record?
  return
else
 update_column(:slug, to_slug)
end
```

Also check the model side **validations**. That may also cause the problems.

Comment: I don't understand why this was voted up. The question is clear that it's an `after_create` callback, so the record should be persisted already.

Answer (score 3):

There is `ActiveRecord::Persistence::ClassMethods#update_columns` method which contains line

```
raise ActiveRecordError, "cannot update a new record" if new_record?
```

therefore you should use `update_all`, for example:

```
 def set_slug
   self.class.where(id: id).update_all(slug: to_slug) if id
 end
```

Hope it will help